# Cropping Background Image Sprite

Tags: css, sprite

is there a way to crop a background sprite?

We have our background image to the CSS body class. Now, if there is not an element with a white background overlaying the rest of the sprite, we have this mess of all the other images there.

I tried background-size, but that doesn't do it. So is there a CSS value that I'm missing that defines not just the background position, but also the actual area the image that should be used?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use background-size along with the width of the actual div. Using them together can crop an image in an image sprite. If you show an example of your code I can give a more fleshed out example.

Comment: Check out [this website](http://www.spritecow.com/) for help with creating CSS for sprites

Comment: the problem is that I am trying to use it on the body class. So, if I restrict the height, I restrict the <body> height. Is there a way around that?

Example:
[link](https://dev2017.purevisionmethod.com/register-account/)

You can see the images below the blue background.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the only way I could work out for this is to put the main body page background at the bottom of the sprite. Assign the correct background-position values and add a background-color: #fff, so the rest of the page becomes readable text.

Thanks for your input!